# Outline rendering of transparent cylinders

Tags: three.js

I am trying to render cylinders for a CAD-like project. As multiple of these will be nested in each other, I am looking to display them similar to this: http://mrwadeturner.pbworks.com/f/1305815353/FC_Cylinder_41702_lg.gif

i.e. I want the outline and the base and bottom circles traced out and the rest should be (semi-)transparent.

Note that this is different from using regular wireframe settings, because that will trace out every face of the sides of the cylinder. The other approach I found - rendering the object twice, once in color and slightly enlarged and once it "regular" version on top - unfortunately won't work either, since multiple cylinders will be nested.

I think this should be possible with custom vertex and fragment shaders, but I am not very proficient in using them. What would be the best way of achieving this effect?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you just need to apply various textures to the same faces. Next you want to try to create custom texture that is going to be a simple transparent .png image with solid dashed border. Then you'll have to set `side:THREE.FrontSide` and `side:THREE.BackSide` to your textures and play around with `depthTest`.

Another approach is to use lines that you age going to create vertex-by-vertex. See this example for custom line implementation: [Hilbert curve](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_lines_colors.html) and [Shapes generation](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am not sure this will work. The problem is that the decision which line will be rendered depends on the projection of the cylinder onto the screen. Effectively I want an outline of the cylinder plus the top and base circles.